# Is it Possible to Add or Subtract from All Times in a Text by Storing it as one String or Something with Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

My problem pertains to times listed in YouTube descriptions. If I want to shave 5 seconds of dead air off the front of say this track description (after shaving 5 seconds off the video), I need a function that will spot and change all the times -5 seconds instead of doing the math myself. I'd like to paste it into the script and copy the output from Terminal to paste into YouTube...
Could I store it as a variable like this and do something to it?

```
times = ("""
Published on Aug 24, 2012
Band: Metallica
Album: Master of Puppets
Released: March 3, 1986
Genre: Thrash Metal

Tracks:
0:00 Battery
5:11 Master Of Puppets
13:46 Welcome Home (Sanitarium)
20:14 The Thing That Should Not Be
26:49 Disposable Heroes
35:04 Leper Messiah
40:46 Orion
49:11 Damage, Inc.
Heres a link for the lyrics
http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/metallica/masterofpuppets.html#1All 
Rights to Metallica!
I do not own any rights!
""")
```

I tried a few things but they all ended up involving a lot of deleting, rewriting, copying, reformatting, separating, etc., but didn't see anything that could make only the changes I'd like to this string with one pass. My attempts to solve would be too elaborate and useless to post here. I ended up giving up and changing all the times by hand with a calculator (on a more complicated video than this example).

Comment: You should show us code that you have written where you attempt to solve this problem yourself. Also, you should tell us precisely what output you expect.

Comment: The output would be the same text with 5 seconds subtracted from every time. I can't show you anything else. I don't know what to do with this aside from copy every time into a string and pass it through some function but the copying and pasting for coding is just as much of a hassle and changing with a calculator by hand.

Comment: How should `0:00` be changed by -5 seconds? Should it stay unchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re, datetime
p = '\d+:\d+'
for i in re.finditer(p, times):
    m, s = i.group().split(':')
    if m != '0' and s != '00':
        time2 = datetime.datetime(* [1] * 4, int(m), int(s)) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
        newtime = ':'.join([str(time2.minute), str(time2.second).zfill(2)])
        print(newtime)
        times = times[:i.start()] + newtime + times[i.end():]
print(times)
```

The `2017, 5, 5, 5` are just holder values -- if anybody knows a better way please say in the comments.

With comments:

```
import re, datetime # import modules
p = '\d+:\d+' # this is a regular expression to match digits, followed by a colon, then more digits (the format all of the times are in)
for i in re.finditer(p, times): # iterate through all of the matches found
    m, s = i.group().split(':') # split time by ':' -- this puts the first number, the minutes, into the m variable, and the seconds into the s variable
    if m != '0' and s != '00': # don't subtract at time="0:00"
        time2 = datetime.datetime(* [1] * 4, int(m), int(s)) # make a datetime to match the time of the video. The important parts are the `int(m), int(s)` to represent the minutes and seconds; the other numbers are just filler and can be changed (but not deleted)
        time2 -= datetime.timedelta(seconds=5) # subtract the five seconds
        newtime = ':'.join([str(time2.minute), str(time2.second).zfill(2)]) # put the time back into string format (zfill pads it with 0s to make it two digits)
        print(newtime)
        times = times[:i.start()] + newtime + times[i.end():] # replace the part of time with the new time. since strings are immutable we need to do this weird technique
print(times)
```

Comment: Nice. I think the tracks should have just one time and should be at the beginning instead. It's better looking, easier for the YouTuber and make make this problem easier.

Comment: Awesome. I'll have to study this code all day. I'm going to clean up my question just to show the string your code works on. You can edit to show only the code that works if you like.

Comment: @user7914198 :) I'll post an explanation at some point today.

Comment: I was just going to take it apart and play with it to learn more. You don't have to. Thanks a million.